# PyInstaller - FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: ''

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I've have seen many posts about this very same error code with many different answers and I still can't fix my problem.

The difference of mine from all the other posts is that I get the following:

```
317 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
318 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\project\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 729, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 676, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\project\main.spec", line 20, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 433, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(self.toc, cdict=kwargs.get('cdict', None),
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 199, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 259, in assemble
    fnm = checkCache(fnm, strip=self.strip_binaries,
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 213, in checkCache
    digest = cacheDigest(fnm, redirects)
  File "c:\users\christopher\desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 358, in cacheDigest
    with open(fnm, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

The file in question is '' (No file at all). I'm new to python and PyInstaller and I am really confused about this.

Comment: Is your file name in english? Maybe that could be a problem. My first suggestion would be to uninstall and reinstall pyinstaller. It's fast and the most common solution to many CS problems :P

Comment: Changed the name and re-installed PyInstaller. Still not working :(

Comment: Are you executing pyinstaller correctly from the cmd?

Comment: I'm doing: pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py

Comment: Are you in the correct directory?

Comment: Yes, I am... :S

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: I'm using version 3.8.2

Comment: Pyinstaller works with Python 2.7, Python 3.5-Python 3.7

Comment: That was it... Thaks!

Comment: @Filip python 2 is officially unsupported. We dropped support in release 3.6.

Comment: @CimimUxMaio expect python 3.8 support in the next two releases, PyInstaller 4.0 and 4.1. It will probably be the latter release though. Please see GitHub.com/PyInstaller/PyInstaller/issues/4311 for details and to track it - you can even set GitHub to notify you when the issue gets closed.

Comment: @Legorooj I read about that but I thought they said this is the last version supporting it. So 3.6 will support Python 2 but later versions won't.

Comment: @Filip no we dropped it in 3.6 - it might work, but it's not supported. (Version 4 won't support it at all - 3.6 didn't actually remove *most* of the support for 2, but 4 will actually not work)

Comment: @Legorooj Hmm weird... Well that is what I got from the docs that's why I commented here. [Pyinstaller Docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). _PyInstaller supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.5+_

Comment: @Filip apologies. I thought harmut had officially removed support for python 2 in 3.6. Apparently I was wrong. I do know that the dev branch and next version *dont'* though: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller#requirements-and-tested-platforms

Comment: @Legorooj Oh no problem, I thought maybe the docs were outdated or made a mistake.

Comment: @Filip :-) - about the docs. Don't use the pythonhosted.com docs, because they are out of date. (PyInstaller3.2=May2016)

Comment: @Legorooj Yeah I figured, I looked at pypi also and another one I am forgetting right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CArchive step PyInstaller tries to bundle the Python DLLs. These names are set dependent on the version, and PyInstaller will return an empty string if it's an unsupported version of python. That is what is causing the error. Please use python 3.5-3.7