# Pyinstaller, --onefile gives me an error when attempting to convert a .py to a .exe within a venv

Tags: python, pyinstaller, file-not-found

I tried turning my .py file into an exe. Pyinstaller only creates an exe when I'm in a venv, so i used a venv to create the exe. It successfully created the exe, when i dont include --onefile. But it doesn't work, so i thought the fix would be by using --onefile. Anyway, When i use the following command in command prompt (pyinstaller --onefile CustomTG.py) with a virtual environment I get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXx2v.png

My python version is (3.8.3).

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471485/pyinstaller-filenotfounderror-no-such-file-or-directory ?

Comment: Could you please include the error message in your question as text rather than as screenshot? A bit more information about the environment (how did you install Python) is also useful.

Comment: i answered this kind of question before. go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255467/how-to-convert-a-python-project-into-an-executable-file-with-all-additional-scri/62272817#62272817)

Comment: Thankyou, but i actually tried py-to-exe, cx_Freeze, and pyinstaller, cx_Freeze creates the exe and when i run it, it actually does what its mean't to do, only issue is that when i send someone the exe or when i change the directory of it. it doesn't work.